# Converting C# struct to F#

Tags: c#, f#

I have code like this in C#:

```
namespace WumpusWorld
    {
        class PlayerAI
        {
            //struct that simulates a cell in the AI replication of World Grid
            struct cellCharacteristics
            {
                public int pitPercentage;
                public int wumpusPercentage;
                public bool isPit;
                public bool neighborsMarked;
                public int numTimesvisited;
            }

            private cellCharacteristics[,] AIGrid;                    //array that simulates World Grid for the AI
            private enum Move { Up, Down, Right, Left, Enter, Escape };   //enum that represents integers that trigger movement in WumpusWorldForm class
            Stack<int> returnPath;                                      //keeps track of each move of AI to trace its path back
            bool returntoBeg;                                           //flag that is triggered when AI finds gold
            int numRandomMoves;                                         //keeps track of the number of random moves that are done

            public PlayerAI()
            {
                AIGrid = new cellCharacteristics[5, 5];
                cellCharacteristics c;
                returntoBeg = false;
                returnPath = new Stack<int>();
                numRandomMoves = 0;

                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                    {
                        c = new cellCharacteristics();
                        c.isPit = false;
                        c.neighborsMarked = false;
                        c.numTimesvisited = 0;

                        AIGrid[x, y] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to convert this C# struct to F# and implement the `struct` into an array like my code above.

Comment: Why don't you just use that C# struct from F#? What exactly have you problems with? What have you tried? BTW, mutable structs are evil and you shouldn't use them unless really necessary.

Comment: it just some small piece from my code, that struct is inside a class, and the class have methods that using the struct as Array. I try convert my C# class into F# class. I add more code into my example code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a struct either using the `struct` keyword (as shown by Stilgar) or using the `Struct` attribute, which looks like this. I also added a constructor that initializes the structure:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type CellCharacteristics =
  val mutable p : int
  val mutable w : int
  val mutable i : bool
  val mutable ne : bool
  val mutable nu : int

  new(_p,_w,_i,_ne,_nu) = 
    { p = _p; w = _w; i = _i; ne = _ne; nu = _nu }

// This is how you create an array of structures and mutate it
let arr = [| CellCharacteristics(1,2,true,false,3) |]
arr.[0].nu <- 42 // Fields are public by default
```

However, it is generally not recommended to use *mutable value types*. This causes confusing behavior and the code is quite difficult to reason about. This is discouraged not just in F#, but even in C# and .NET in general. In F#, creating an immutable struct is also easier:

```ml
// The fields of the strcuct are specified as part of the constructor
// and are stored in automatically created (private) fileds
[<Struct>]
type CellCharacteristics(p:int, w:int, i:bool, ne:bool, nu:int) =
  // Expose fields as properties with a getter
  member x.P = p
  member x.W = w
  member x.I = i
  member x.Ne = ne
  member x.Nu = nu
```

When using immutable structs, you won't be able to modify individual fields of the struct. You'll need to replace the entire struct value in the array instead. You can typically implement calculation as a member of the struct (say `Foo`) and then just write `arr.[0] <- arr.[0].Foo()` to perform the update.

Comment: i kind of understand about your code, but i still don't get it when i want to implement it in my code. In my code, the struct is in a class, and in C# i can implement the struct into an array easily. I can't explain this better, because my English aren't good. If you don't mind, please take a look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126680/need-help-to-convert-my-homework-from-c-sharp-to-f

Comment: oh sorry, it seems i broke the rules, so the link is closed